# How can I access the neighboring elements of the matrix using numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

I have made a code that calculates the dissolution of fluids, the problem is that the code is very poor, so I have been looking at that with numpy I can optimize it but I have been stuck without knowing how to do the following code using numpy and the roll function. Basically I have a matrix that the index and cannot be more than 1024, for this I use% to calculate what index it is. But this takes a long time.

I tried using numpy, using roll, rotating the matrix and then I don't have to calculate the module. But I don't know how to take the values ​​of the neighbors.

```
def evolve(grid, dt, D=1.0):
  xmax, ymax = grid_shape
  new_grid = [[0.0,] * ymax for x in range(xmax)]
  for i in range(xmax):
    for j in range(ymax):
      grid_xx = grid[(i+1)%xmax][j] + grid[(i-1)%xmax][j] - 2.0 * grid[i][j]
      grid_yy = grid[i][(j+1)%ymax] + grid[i][(j-1)%ymax] - 2.0 * grid[i][j]
      new_grid[i][j] = grid[i][j] + D * (grid_xx + grid_yy) * dt
  return new_grid
```

Comment: You are not using numpy in the code you've shown. What did you try with numpy?

Comment: I am not using numpy because I wrote the code without numpy, but my teacher told me that I can optimize this code using numpy and the roll function, first I have to change everything to numpy but I don't know how, and then try to optimize the code. I'm a little lost because I've never optimized code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to rewrite the `evolve` function from (almost) zero using `numpy`.

Here the guidelines:

- First, `grid` must be a 2D numpy array, not a list of lists.
- Your teacher suggested the roll function: look at its [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html) and try to understand how it works. `roll` will solve the problem of finding neighbour entries in the matrix by shifting (or rolling) the matrix over one of the axis. You can then create shifted versions of `grid` in the four directions and use them, instead of searching for neighbours.
- Once you have the shifted `grid`s, you'll see that you will not need the for loops to calculate each cell of `new_grid`: you can use vectorized calculation, which is faster.

So the code will look like this:

```
def evolve(grid, dt, D=1.0):
    if not isinstance(grid, np.ndarray): #ensuring that is a numpy array.
        grid = np.array(grid)
    u_grid = np.roll(grid, 1, axis=0)
    d_grid = np.roll(grid, -1, axis=0)
    r_grid = np.roll(grid, 1, axis=1)
    l_grid = np.roll(grid, -1, axis=1)
    new_grid = grid + D * (u_grid + d_grid + r_grid + l_grid - 4.0*grid) * dt
    return new_grid
```

With a 1024 x 1024 matrix, each numpy `evolve` takes (on my machine) ~0.15 seconds to return the `new_grid`. Your `evolve` with the for loops takes ~3.85 seconds.

Comment: Please, don't post code in the comment, it is unreadable. Better to open a new question. Remember that "does not do it well" is not a good statement, explain clearly why it does not work as explected (i.e. clarify what you wish to get and what you get instead). It my answer was useful, please consider to accept it.